# Boost MinCut from MaxFlow

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I need to get an st-MinCut of a graph. I recently started using the C++ Boost libraries, which don't seem to have that st-MinCut functionality, but the do have MaxFlow implementations and I can (in theory) make use of the MaxFlow/MinCut duality.

I have gotten the "push relabel max flow" function working properly, but I can't figure out how to run a DFS, from the source along edges where the residual capacity are greater than 0, to get the nodes on the source side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filtered_graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/filtered_graph.html) to create a (virtual) graph that only has the edges with non-zero residual capacity (or any other criteria)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in following way (LEDA graph library has a function which will do it for you). I iterated over all edges on the graph and collect all edges which are either saturated or have zero flow. Now a subset of these edges must be a min-cut.

Then I used `gsl_combination.h` to generate subsets of this set. Each subset was checked if its cut value is equal to the max-flow. If no, then generate next subset, if yes, then check if removing these edges from graph will break the graph into two-pieces. Now your problem is how to check if removing certain edges from graph breaks the graph into two pieces such that one piece has source and other sink node.

This is simple. Remove from graph those edges given as possible cut-set. Create a stack `ss` and push source node to it. Now create a while loop which terminates when `ss` is empty. Inside loop, `pop` node from `ss` and get all out-going edges from `ss`; push to `ss` `target` vertex for these edges. If during iteration, you find a node which is equal to sink node that means the both source and sink has a path between them. Therefore it is not a cut. I am putting a fragment of code. Notice that I am not removing edges from the graph, I am merely setting their flow to 0. I take all edges which has zero flow as edges removed from graph.

```
template<typename Graph>
vector<typename Graph::edge_descriptor> getMinCutWhenFlowIsGiven(
    Graph& flowG, typename Graph::vertex_descriptor src
    , typename Graph::vertex_descriptor tgt
    , unsigned flow)
{
  /* Find saturated edges */
  vector<typename Graph::edge_descriptor> possibleCutEdges;
  unsigned totalCutWeight = 0;

  /* Find all saturated or zero-flow edges. */
  for(auto e = edges(flowG); e.first != e.second; e.first++)
  {
    typename Graph::edge_descriptor ee = *e.first;
    if(flowG[ee].flow == 0 || flowG[ee].capacity - flowG[ee].flow == 0)
    {
      possibleCutEdges.push_back(ee);
      totalCutWeight += flowG[ee].flow;
      cerr << flowG[ee].flow << ",";
    }
  }
  cerr << endl;
  cerr << "[INFO] Total " << possibleCutEdges.size() << " edges." 
    << " with capacity : " << totalCutWeight 
    << " in flow-network after flow-computation." << endl;


#if  SAVE_GRAPH
  /* Save this graph. */
  write_graph(flowG, "dots/overlap.ml");
#endif     /* -----  SAVE_GRAPH  ----- */


  /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Good, now we have a set of vertices. Generate all possible subsets of set
   * and see if any of them satisfy our need.
   *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  size_t n = possibleCutEdges.size();

  vector<typename Graph::edge_descriptor> cut;

  gsl_combination *c;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    c = gsl_combination_calloc (n, i);
    do
    {
      /* Check if this combination satify the max-flow condition */
      unsigned edgesFlow = 0;
      vector<typename Graph::edge_descriptor> potentialCut;
      for(size_t ii = 0; ii < c->k; ii++)
      {
        size_t elem = gsl_combination_get(c, ii);
        edgesFlow += flowG[possibleCutEdges[elem]].flow;
        potentialCut.push_back(possibleCutEdges[elem]);
      }
      if(edgesFlow == flow)
      {
        if(isCut(potentialCut, flowG, src, tgt))
          return potentialCut;  // got it!
      }
    }
    while (gsl_combination_next (c) == GSL_SUCCESS);
    gsl_combination_free (c);
  }
  return cut;
}
```